# Convert NSData to JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `NSData` object, i need to convert it a `NSDictionary` object.

```
NSData *data = ....;
```

Now i need to convert this to a `NSDictionary`, How can i do this programatically ?

note: After i save the `NSData` to the `NSDictionary` i should be able to access `key value` pairs of the `NSDictionary`.

I don't have a code to demonstrate my workings so far, I have only created the NSData object, and have no clue to continue :)

Comment: And what format is `data` in? You're going to need some logic to convert whatever it is into a dictionary unless it's in one of the standard serialisation formats.

Comment: Is it JSON data which you want to convert ?

Comment: Yes it is JSON data. Can someone show me a sample code or a tutorial that demonstrates the conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass MKNetworkOperation and override the responseJSON method with the following:

```
-(id) responseJSON
{
    NSString *rawJSON;
    id jsonValue = nil;
    if ((rawJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) != nil) {
        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        if ((jsonValue = [jsonParser objectWithString:rawJSON]) == nil) {
            NSLog(@"This string doesn't seem to be JSON: '%@'\nraw Data : '%s'", rawJSON, (char *)[[self responseData] bytes]);
            return [self responseString];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"This data doesn't seem to be an UTF8 encoded string: %@", [self responseData]);
        return [self responseString];
    }

    return jsonValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check this link of stack overflow, I have already consumed the JSON services, it will help you a lot. All of the coding is there.

[JSON Data Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890808/json-array-for-picker-view-iphone)

And here is the tutorial with sample project

[JSON Parse Tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/)

Hope you would find it helpful

Comment: I haven't use that, I like to use iOS native methods and frameworks, try it NSJSONSerialization you will find it more easy to serialize and deserialize

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend invoking [SBJSON framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/), it saved my time for many times, exactly finished my work and easily to use. You don't need to know the details of the conversion algorithm, just download and invoke it.

You might want to download it from [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/), then follow [this tutorial](http://jasarien.com/?p=428) to get your things done.

Comment: Sorry I have not yet used MKNetworkKit. I feel lucky to find SBJSON at the first time when I need a JSON parser. I suggest you turn to use SBJSON, or you might want to modify your question in order to ask specific problem about MKNetworkKit. Hope I could help.