# Sending byte data to web service in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to send my Byte data using some existed web service . Now i don't want to explore on Web service more but i just want my following Byte data to some already existed web service.
for Example , following is my Byte Data .

```
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, (Byte*)myData, len);
```

How can i do this !? i want to use Existed Web Service only,your help would be appreciated a lot .

**EDITED**

i have my NSData in json format too . as below code

```
const unsigned char *bytes = [myData bytes]; // no need to copy the data

NSUInteger length = [myData length];

NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];
}

NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          byteArray, @"vedio",
                          nil];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJson options:0 error:NULL];
```

Comment: What parameters does your web service take in?

Comment: Exactly how does the web service receive the data? What format (JSON, XML, URL parameters ...) does it expect?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i am very new to this part called web service, somehow i need to send my data in byte format to my web service , i  am going to use Json & post method as given in this link               http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service ... still i am confused on how can i do this ..

Comment: see if ASI request can take input from NSData which is normally used to store and transfer arbitrary data (ie any memory buffer). How to init NSData with bytes should come up via google.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D what you mean by ASI request!? .. & i have already init my NSData .. now, how can i send my bytes to web service . can you please give me some link on this , so i could be more clear on this

Comment: You said you were using the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and that uses the ASIHttpRequest class. You didn't mention in your question that you already have an NSData ready to send out. So what's left seems to be converting NSData to JSON, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972775/convert-nsdata-to-json

Comment: @LearnCocos2D according to my EDIT , now i have my data into json too ..actually i want to send my data bytes of one small video to web service . now i have my all data ready in json format ..Now if i want to send all those bytes in POST method then what i have to do !! can u please guide me on this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simply send my NSdata or say ByteData like this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictParam = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dictParam setValue:mydata forKey:@"pattern"];

NSString *Web_str_pattern = @"my webservice link";

JSONParser *parser = [[JSONParser alloc]initWith_withURL:Web_str_pattern withParam:dictParam withData:nil withType:kPostURL withSelector:@selector(getData:) withObject:self];
```

Here , i am using JSONParser for web service.