# Passing returned data into array,iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, ipad

I m using JSON and while parsing, i m getting the returned value as

```
> [{"id":"2","name":"a"}, {"id":"3","name":"b"},
> {"id":"104","name":"c"}, {"id":"4","name":"d"}]
```

I want to have the 'name' in some array, so that i can show the names in picker view.

from array to pickerview, i can perform,but i m getting problem in retrieving the values of name and put into an array.

Comment: `I m using JSON and while parsing, i m getting the returned value as` I don't quite get this? How do you parse? As a term of parse, after parsing you should have a `NSArray` object filled with `NSDictionary` objects with keys `id` and `name`, from which you can take the values...

Comment: Refer to this stackoverflow post: [JSON Parse][1]

Hope this will help you

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890808/json-array-for-picker-view-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jsonArray = [{"id":"2","name":"a"}, {"id":"3","name":"b"},
 {"id":"104","name":"c"}, {"id":"4","name":"d"}]

NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in jsonArray){
   NSString *str =  [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
   if(str){      
         [nameArray addObject:str];
    }
}
```

This your name array... hope this will help you

Comment: You took returned json values into jsonArray first? how

Comment: The JSON array is same your json value... your json value is an array which contains 4 key... i hope u understood and i m returning only name value in that array... you need it same right??

Comment: NSMutableArray *jsonList......thats same as jsonarray.got it.That worked....thank Abhishek.exactly what i was trying.

Comment: Hello Abhishek, can we take the whole thing in dictionary? so that, when put the names into pickerview,and onselect ,i can  have the id also?

Comment: i cant vote up, untill i hv 15...i will put in my reminder....for sure.once i m above 15 i m gonna upvote .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of JSON parser library, which makes a discrete data collection type (for example, an NSDictionary or NSArray) out of the JSON string. I've written one library which I prefer:

https://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON/

There are also a lot of older and probably better solutions; consider JSONKit:

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

And SBJSON (a. k. a. JSON framework):

https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

jsonArray = [{"id":"2","name":"a"}, {"id":"3","name":"b"},
 {"id":"104","name":"c"}, {"id":"4","name":"d"}]

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.count;i++){
   if([[jsonArray objeactAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"])
   {
          NSString *str =[[jsonArray objeactAtIndex:i] 
          objectForKey:@"name"];
         [nameArray addObject:str];
    }
}
```

Its Working Properly.